# JS not rendering in Rails 5.1.6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attending to add JavaScript to my Rails 5.1.6 project and am getting the following errors in the console:

```
 VM18462:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at DOMEval (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:83)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:347)
    at text script (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:9607)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:8755)
    at done (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:9223)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js?body=1:9515)
```

and

```
VM18463:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:244)
    at rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:173
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:228)
```

the following is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and the controller action that is attempting to render a simple alert in a js.erb file:

```
def search
        if params[:stock].blank? #what is the diff between .blank? and .present?
            flash.now[:danger] = "Stock cannot be blank"
            render 'users/portfolio'
        else
            @stock = Stock.find_stock(params[:stock])
            flash.now[:danger] = "Please enter valid stock" unless @stock 
            if @stock 
                respond_to do |format| 
                    format.js { render partial: 'users/stock_result' }
                end 
            end 
        end
        
    end
```

not sure whats going on here, i have a feeling its something to do with the way ive set things up in application.js.

rails 5.1.6
ruby 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake.  The partial that i created to handle the JS was misnamed, I forgot the "_" at the beginning of the filename